# Не скрывать системную клавиатуру во фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin, клавиатура

Есть фрагменты с текстовыми полями. На них вызывается системная клавиатура:

```
val imm: InputMethodManager =
            view.context!!.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
```

Однако, при появлении какого-либо уведомления или ввода в одно текстовое поле - клавиатура скрывается. Как сделать так, чтобы пока фрагмент открыт - клавиатура не сворачивалась и была активна?

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что это поможет конкретно в вашем кейсе, но вы можете попробовать этот способ.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```